# Jquery Auto-Complete code from JSON array

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am trying to write a custom autocomplete piece for a form, where once you start typing, the suggestions show under the input field. as you type the options get more and more specific. The options are being fed by a JSON array, dynamically created by a mysql query to the database.

Upon clicking on one of the listed options, the click action should fill the input value with the value of the clicked element on the list.

For some reason, I seem to have an issue with the click jquery action on the list of options.

Can someone please look at this source code and help me figure out why is it that it is not working?

I created simplified version of this on jsfiddle.net and it worked, once I put my full code in there it breaks!.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var partsArray = [
    {"label": "0030200-08"}, 
    {"label": "005-2060-6"}, 
    {"label": "005-2063-5"}, 
    {"label": "005-2067-1"}, 
    {"label": "005-2078-3"}, 
    {"label": "005-2119-8"}, 
    {"label": "0062260-16"}, 
    {"label": "007-0026-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0028-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0030-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0031-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0032-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0033-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0035-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0036-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0038-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0039-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0039-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0050-0"}, 
    {"label": "007-0051-0"}, 
    {"label": "012-5060-0"}, 
    {"label": "017-0035-0"}, 
    {"label": "017-0041-0"}, 
    {"label": "017-0042-0"}, 
    {"label": "017-0074-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-2055-1"}, 
    {"label": "019-2084-3"}, 
    {"label": "019-2084-6"}, 
    {"label": "019-2099-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-2102-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-2129-2"}, 
    {"label": "019-2151-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-2239-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-2306-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-2313-6"}, 
    {"label": "019-2539-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-3124-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-5065-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-6006-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-6019-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-7042-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-7072-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-7089-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8046-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8072-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8073-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8074-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8078-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8093-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8094-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8095-0"}, 
    {"label": "019-8101-0"}, 
    {"label": "023-0115-0"}, 
    {"label": "023-0122-0"}, 
    {"label": "026-0018-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0006-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0022-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0097-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0286-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0339-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0352-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0362-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0407-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0461-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0463-0"}, 
    {"label": "029-0681-0"}, 
    {"label": "030-0035-0"}, 
    {"label": "030-1045-2"}, 
    {"label": "030-1046-0"}, 
    {"label": "030-1107-3"}, 
    {"label": "030-2002-0"}, 
    {"label": "030-2227-2"}, 
    {"label": "030-2248-0"}, 
    {"label": "030-2295-0"}, 
    {"label": "030-2367-0"}, 
    {"label": "030-2705-0"}, 
    {"label": "031-0105-0"}, 
    {"label": "031-0106-0"}, 
    {"label": "031-0112-2"}, 
    ];
    </script>
    <style>
    li{
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #888;
    }
    li:hover{
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .suggestions{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #CCC;
    left: 3px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="InputSpace" id="inputSpace">
        <div class="suggestionsContainer">
            <ul class="list">
        <div class="suggestions">
        </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <script>
    var typed;
    var a = 1;
    $("#inputSpace").keyup(function(){
        typed = $("#inputSpace").val();
            for(var x = 0; x < partsArray.length; x++){
                if(partsArray[x].label.substring(0,a) == typed){
                    $(".suggestions").append("<li name='"+partsArray[x].label+"'>"+partsArray[x].label+"</li>");
                }
                    else
                {
                    continue;
                }
             }
             a=a+1;
        });

    $("input").keypress(function(){
        $(".suggestions").html("");
    });


        $(".list li").click(function(){
            var number=$(this).attr("name");
            $("input").val(number);
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the link to your fiddle?

Comment: I did not save it!! :(    (...Lesson learned...) sorry!...

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(".list li").click(function(){
        var= number=$(this).attr("name");
        $("input").val(number);
```

In above lines you added `var = number = ...` . I think you should write it in following way,

```
 var number=$(this).attr("name");
```

remove "=" sign between 'var' and 'number'.

May be , it can solve your problem .

Comment: Good catch on the typo

Comment: I noticed that little detail a couple minutes ago and modified it  as well... No dice !!! thanks for the observation!

Comment: If you will find any solution for this on your own then dont forget to post it, so i can be able use your code.

Comment: Absolutely!... So far... no luck!. I think it is in fact coming from the JSON array call... But still trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I made a revision to my answer. I've made some minor style tweaks to your code. Most importantly, I replaced the CDN version of jQuery because it was throwing an error. I tested it locally and it worked perfectly. Always remember to check the console in your browser dev tools.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var partsArray = [
            {"label": "0030200-08"}, 
            {"label": "005-2060-6"}, 
            {"label": "005-2063-5"}, 
            {"label": "005-2067-1"}, 
            {"label": "005-2078-3"}, 
            {"label": "005-2119-8"}, 
            {"label": "0062260-16"}, 
            {"label": "007-0026-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0028-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0030-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0031-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0032-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0033-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0035-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0036-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0038-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0039-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0039-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0050-0"}, 
            {"label": "007-0051-0"}, 
            {"label": "012-5060-0"}, 
            {"label": "017-0035-0"}, 
            {"label": "017-0041-0"}, 
            {"label": "017-0042-0"}, 
            {"label": "017-0074-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-2055-1"}, 
            {"label": "019-2084-3"}, 
            {"label": "019-2084-6"}, 
            {"label": "019-2099-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-2102-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-2129-2"}, 
            {"label": "019-2151-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-2239-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-2306-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-2313-6"}, 
            {"label": "019-2539-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-3124-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-5065-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-6006-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-6019-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-7042-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-7072-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-7089-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8040-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8046-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8072-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8073-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8074-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8078-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8093-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8094-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8095-0"}, 
            {"label": "019-8101-0"}, 
            {"label": "023-0115-0"}, 
            {"label": "023-0122-0"}, 
            {"label": "026-0018-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0006-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0022-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0097-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0286-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0339-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0352-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0362-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0407-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0461-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0463-0"}, 
            {"label": "029-0681-0"}, 
            {"label": "030-0035-0"}, 
            {"label": "030-1045-2"}, 
            {"label": "030-1046-0"}, 
            {"label": "030-1107-3"}, 
            {"label": "030-2002-0"}, 
            {"label": "030-2227-2"}, 
            {"label": "030-2248-0"}, 
            {"label": "030-2295-0"}, 
            {"label": "030-2367-0"}, 
            {"label": "030-2705-0"}, 
            {"label": "031-0105-0"}, 
            {"label": "031-0106-0"}, 
            {"label": "031-0112-2"}, 
    ];

    var typed;
    var a = 1;

    $("#inputSpace").keyup(function(){

            typed = $("#inputSpace").val();

            var i = 0;
            for(var x = 0; x < partsArray.length; x++){

                    if ( partsArray[x].label.substring(0,a) == typed ) {
                            $(".suggestions").append("<li name='"+partsArray[i].label+"'>"+partsArray[x].label+"</li>");
                    }

            }
            i++;
            a=a+1;

    });

    $("input").keypress(function(){
            $(".suggestions").html("");
    });

    $(".list").on( "click", "li", function() {
        var indexNum = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#inputSpace").val(indexNum);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried what you mentioned here, unfortunately I am getting the same behaviour. I am experiencing one of those Code-Induced Brain farts!! I know the concept is very close!! and I am very close !!! but do not seem to be able to see it!!!

Comment: Try appending directly to <ul class="list">? I dont advise placing DIV's inside UL tags

Comment: minor detail with the suggestion class not expanding, but the behaviour continues on the list items not triggering on click. Thanks for your super quick responses! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Still no success... If someone figures this out... Please post!

Comment: I have copied your code and played with it... for some reason it seems not to identify the li tags even when I put a class or an id. I am at a loss! I have had similar projects with tasks where you create an unordered list and I have been able to call the value of that li to be used for different purposes.. not sure why this is just not working!!

Comment: Very strange. It worked like a charm for me in Chrome. Am I missing something? Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/na7e8m19/

Comment: I just looked at it... If it worked on your browser, it makes me think I may have an issue with my computer!! Since when I click on the <li> it does not populate the input value in your JSFiddle sample... As I mentioned on my answer... And in fact I used your version of the code for this as well... I nested a second function inside the $(".suggestions").click(function() where i added a mouseover to populate the input value instead of a click, yet kept the click for ipad users too.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question and had to read it again for clarity. Please look at the fiddle example again.  :)  http://jsfiddle.net/na7e8m19/7/

Answer (score 0):

So... After so much trial and error... I figured it out!!

The answer rests under nesting a new function for the li inside the suggestions class.

```
$(".suggestions").click(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        var name = $(this).html();
        $("#inputSpace").val(name);
    })
});
```

This in exchange takes the value of the list item and replaces the input value with it.!!

What a headache! but there it is!!! Thanks you everyone for your suggestions and your assistance!